# Passing argument through environment variable, is it completely safe?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sh, command-line-arguments, sanitization

I need to invoke `wget` from a server application with parts of the url controlled by the user. If I store the arguments in an environment variable `URL` using `setenv()` in the server application, then execute in the forked shell

```
wget somehost/"$URL"
```

can I assume that `$URL` is not expanded in any way and it is interpreted wholly as a part of the url? Is this compatible with the Bourne shell (so `sh` and not `bash` in e.g. Ubuntu)?

Comment: How do you run wget from the server application? Using `system()`?

Comment: Double quoted variables shouldn't be expanded or interpreted by any POSIX-compatible shell.

Comment: Probable issues: 1. If the spawned shell sources `.bashrc`, then it will pickup the `URL` in there if it exists. 2. If you spawn multiple processes with different `URL`, some of them may pickup the wrong `URL` .

Comment: @PSkocik Single quotes prevent expansion. Double quotes don't.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Shouldn't be expanded or interpreted *after they're expanded* is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

The shell will perform parameter expansion of `$URL` before it invokes (forks/execs) the `wget` command. Since you have the parameter in double quotes, no word splitting is performed and "somehost/whatever URL expands to" will be one argument.

The result may be visible for other users in `ps(1)` output as command plus args.

In addition, data stored in environment variables may be visible, if the `ps(1)` implementation on your system supports `-e` to show the environment (e.g. FreeBSD does).

If your question is, can you hide sensitive information such as access credentials this way, the answer in general is "no".

Comment: I'm just concerned with command injection, so if I understand correctly that's fine.